# r parse httr GET response into single data frame

Tags: r, json, data.table, httr

I am having trouble parsing the response from a GET command to what I want it to be. The goal is to get a data frame with a column for each of the columns that GET returns. The code to generate the response is below except for the missing value for `wosliteKey`. The response data, in RDS form, is [here](https://uofi.box.com/s/y3iqifxv9wb2zz3j03keoofzh1dva352). It's a 16k file. I tried `dput` but its too big to paste into this text area.

```
count <- 100
url <- 'https://api.clarivate.com/api/woslite/'
query <- 'ts=(land AND ocean AND climate AND change AND food security) AND PY=2013-2019'
response <- httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(accept = 'application/json', `X-APIKey` = wosliteKey),  query = list(databaseId = 'WOK', usrQuery = query, count = count, firstRecord = firstRecord))
```

I convert the response to a json type file using the following two commands

```
jsonRespText <- content(response, "text") 
  j <- fromJSON(jsonRespText)
```

This results in a data frame with some complicated elements. Here's the output from `str(j, max.level = 3)`. Several of the elements of data are nested data frames whose columns are lists.

I want all the the columns of the nested data frames be columns in a single data frame. All columns are character.

Using `jData <- as.data.table(flatten(j$Data))`
   I get a 27 column data table. But each column is a list.

```
List of 2
 $ QueryResult:List of 3
  ..$ QueryID        : int 2
  ..$ RecordsSearched: int 71811425
  ..$ RecordsFound   : int 66
 $ Data       :'data.frame':    66 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ Keyword:'data.frame': 66 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ Keywords:List of 66
  ..$ Title  :'data.frame': 66 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ Title:List of 66
  ..$ Doctype:'data.frame': 66 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ Doctype:List of 66
  ..$ Author :'data.frame': 66 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Authors         :List of 66
  .. ..$ BookGroupAuthors:List of 66
  ..$ Source :'data.frame': 66 obs. of  9 variables:
  .. ..$ Pages               :List of 66
  .. ..$ SupplementNumber    :List of 66
  .. ..$ SourceTitle         :List of 66
  .. ..$ SpecialIssue        :List of 66
  .. ..$ Volume              :List of 66
  .. ..$ Published.BiblioDate:List of 66
  .. ..$ Published.BiblioYear:List of 66
  .. ..$ Issue               :List of 66
  .. ..$ BookSeriesTitle     :List of 66
  ..$ UT     : chr [1:66] "WOS:000317372700003" "WOS:000367881500035" "WOS:000399397700046" "WOS:000419351000013" ...
  ..$ Other  :'data.frame': 66 obs. of  12 variables:
  .. ..$ Identifier.Eissn                      :List of 66
  .. ..$ Contributor.ResearcherID.Names        :List of 66
  .. ..$ Contributor.ResearcherID.ResearcherIDs:List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Doi                        :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Issn                       :List of 66
  .. ..$ ResearcherID.Disclaimer               :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Ids                        :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.article_no                 :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Eisbn                      :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Isbn                       :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Parent_Book_Doi            :List of 66
  .. ..$ Identifier.Xref_Doi                   :List of 66
```

I can convert these lists to character columns with

```
jData[, ] <- lapply(jData[, ], as.character)
```

but I'm nervous that I might be losing something along the way. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how you generated woslitekey

Answer (score 0):

What is usually parsed from JSON is list with sub-list  or list with sub data frames. I think the best approach and the more clear approach you can do is use a code to split the results in to separate data frames.

Example
create a new DATA table and then cbind Keyword,title,and doctype. Then cbind authors and then BookGroupAuthors and so on. I am pretty sure there is something faster but this makes sure you have a big dataframe with all the columns retrieved from Json.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).